# Links are sometimes wrong on mobile

Tags: bug, usability

I'm using an iPhone and clicking on things on a  page is *sometimes* borken in weird ways. For example, the link to this meta site actually linked to http://superuser.com/ for me just now. Clicking on questions often takes me to a different question, a tag, or a user's profile page, often apparently links which were near the one I actually clicked on. Similarly, when viewing a question, clicking on a link sometimes takes me to an adjacent link. But every time I decide I want to report this, the symptom disappears.

I have seen it maybe half a dozen times in the last couple of months, only ever on my iPhone, where I use http://grazingbrowser.com/ and only ever on Unix & Linux, never on Stack Overflow which I visit a lot more often.

Here is a screenshot from this very page where I have clicked open my "supercollider" inbox and held down my finger on the comment on a Procmail question I receved today. There is no way I could have misclicked this large target seven-eight times in a row, enough to persuade my phone to let me finally get a representative screen shot with all the pertinent details included after several attempts. The phone displays options for the link I clicked; you'll notice that the URL is for a chat comment, corresponding to the next entry in the inbox menu.

[image: Clicked Procmail comment, got chat link]

Comment: Appreciate any hints for better tags to use on this.

Comment: Is this then a site bug or a browser bug?

Comment: I *think* it's a site bug because like I wrote, Stack Overflow has worked fine for years, and I only had this happen when I started to visit Unix & Linux more often.

Comment: Just as a problem filtering device, try using the same browser on another, or more than one, stack that is a subdomain of stackexchange.com rather than it's own site like Stack Overflow is. It could be the addition of the subdomain is messing up the browser somehow. I have had similar problems, but I believe mine have always been the result of fat fingers on a small screen.

Comment: I think I can rule out fat fingers, I was able to repro on some pages consistently but then when I reloaded enough times it was gone.